# HTML checkbox is not clickable in some cases

Tags: html, checkbox

I was creating a spoiler which uses a checkbox as input.

The problem with this is that only the first row is perfectly clickable.

Other Checkboxes are only clickable in some places.

Picture
[image]

An other weird this is when the first spoiler is checked. 
Picture
[image]
All places are fully clickable again.

HTML/PHP

```
<div class="maasduin-container">
  <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" /> 
  <label for="spoiler" >Appartementen</label>
  <div class="spoiler">
    <?php
                foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
                {
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinCategory'] == 'Appartementen'): ?>
                            <div class="products">
                                <div class="maasduin-foto"><img style="width: 136px; height: 134px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinImage']; ?>">
                                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinPas'] == '1'): ?>
                                        <div class="maasduin-actiefoto">
                                            <img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinPasfoto']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="maasduin-naam"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?></h3></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-locatie"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinLocatie']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-email"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinEmail']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-telefoon"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinTelefoon']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-website"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinWebsite']; ?></div>                    
                        </div>
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php
                }
                    ?>      
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" /> 
                    </div>



  <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler2" /> 
  <label for="spoiler2" >Bed and Breakfast</label>
  <div class="spoiler">
    <?php
                foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
                {
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinCategory'] == 'Bed and Breakfast'): ?>
                            <div class="products">
                                <div class="maasduin-foto"><img style="width: 136px; height: 134px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinImage']; ?>">
                                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinPas'] == '1'): ?>
                                        <div class="maasduin-actiefoto">
                                            <img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinPasfoto']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="maasduin-naam"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?></h3></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-locatie"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinLocatie']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-email"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinEmail']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-telefoon"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinTelefoon']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-website"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinWebsite']; ?></div>                    
                        </div>
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php
                }
                    ?>      
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler2" />
                </div>
```

CSS

```
 input[id^="spoiler"]{
 display: none;
}
input[id^="spoiler"] + label {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: #22CF00;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
}
input[id^="spoiler"]:checked + label {
  color: black;
  background: #0EC100;
}
input[id^="spoiler"] ~ .spoiler {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
input[id^="spoiler"]:checked + label + .spoiler{
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap each element in separate div with row class.

> .row { Width :100%; Float:left; Position relative; }

Then you will have better controll of each element in this row and if IT wont help you can Little workaround and set transparent div on position absolute and with z index you will get clickable div on top of element :)